# Função mail() não envia o e-mail

Tags: php, email

Transferi agora um site em que estou a trabalhar para um servidor remoto e reparei agora que o mail não chega à minha caixa de entrada do gmail. Utilizei um metodo muito simples de código mas não funciona, apesar de aparecer escrito ""O seu email foi enviado com sucesso! ":

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$carga_type = $_POST['carga_type'];
$weight = $_POST['weight'];
$local = $_POST['local'];
$destiny = $_POST['destiny'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$tele = $_POST['tele'];
$vol_number = $_POST['vol_number'];
$volume = $_POST['volume'];
$size = $_POST['size'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];

$to = "meuemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Nova messagem";
$message = "De: ".$name."<br>
            Email: ".$email."<br>
            Tipo de carga: ".$carga_type."<br>
            Peso: ".$weight."<br>
            Local: ".$local."<br>
            Destino: ".$destiny."<br>
            Data: ".$date."<br>
            empresa: ".$company."<br>
            Telefone: ".$tele."<br>
            Número de volumes: ".$vol_number."<br>
            Volume: ".$volume."<br>
            Medidas C x L x A: ".$size."<br>
            Notas: ".$notes."<br><br>";

echo ($message);
if (($name == "") || ($carga_type == "") || ($date == "") || ($local == "") || ($tele == "") || ($vol_number==""))
{
echo 'Preencha todos os os campos mínimos necessários (Nome, Tipo de carga, Data, Local e Numero de telefone.)';
}
else
{
    mail($to, $subject, $message);
    echo "O seu email foi enviado com sucesso! ";
}
?>
```

Comment: vc setou o `from`? veja tbm se o retorno `mail()` é false adicionando um if.

Comment: Não creio que seja preciso pelo que vi aqui só esses 3três campos são necessários (to, subject, message) http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Comment: faça o seguinte teste, adicone essas 2 linhas no inicio da sua página: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` e a linha de mail para: 
`if(!mail($to, $subject, $message)){
   echo  error_get_last();
}`

Comment: Você configurou o servidor SMTP remoto no PHP ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: @Perdeu Obrigado mas não há nenhum erro, tudo corre normalmente ("O seu email foi enviado com sucesso! ")

Comment: Como configuro esse servidor SMTP no remoto?

Comment: @Miguel geralmente o pessoal deixa o mecanismo de envio de e-mails na própria máquina. Qual é o sistema operacional e/ou hospedagem?

Answer (score 2):

Tente isto (tendo em atenção que o serviço SMTP está a funcionar correctamente no servidor):

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $carga_type = $_POST['carga_type'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $local = $_POST['local'];
    $destiny = $_POST['destiny'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $tele = $_POST['tele'];
    $vol_number = $_POST['vol_number'];
    $volume = $_POST['volume'];
    $size = $_POST['size'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];

    $to = "meuemail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Nova messagem";
    $message = "De: ".$name."<br>
                Email: ".$email."<br>
                Tipo de carga: ".$carga_type."<br>
                Peso: ".$weight."<br>
                Local: ".$local."<br>
                Destino: ".$destiny."<br>
                Data: ".$date."<br>
                empresa: ".$company."<br>
                Telefone: ".$tele."<br>
                Número de volumes: ".$vol_number."<br>
                Volume: ".$volume."<br>
                Medidas C x L x A: ".$size."<br>
                Notas: ".$notes."<br><br>";


            $headers = "From: $from \r\n".

                       "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .

                       "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

            if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
echo "email enviado com sucesso";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Já me aconteceu isso e adicionei um cabeçalho e funcionou, no meu caso.
Veja um exemplo:

```
$headers = 'From: Titulo da aplicacao <no-reply@dominio.com>'."\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: no-reply@dominio.com '. "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: MyFunction/' . phpversion().
        'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n".
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

mail($email,$titulo,$HTML,$headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

veja se nao é postfix (nao sendmail), se for basta adicionar o ('-r ' . $sender) no final da funcao mail

ex:

```
 if( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers, '-r'.$sender) ){
  echo "enviado";
 }
```

onde $sender deve ser o email que esta enviando a mensagem, é uma configuracao adicional alem dos headers necessario pelo postfix.

Answer (score -1):

Alguns servidores de hospedagem requerem autenticação para enviar e-mails programaticamente. E não está sendo exibido nenhum erro, pois do jeito que você escreveu seu código, independente do resultado da função mail() vc da um echo com a frase "O seu email foi enviado com sucesso! ".
Considere usar a classe PHPMailer, ela facilita bastante essas configurações de envio de e-mail, inclusive com smtp autenticado.

Comment: A parte inicial da sua afirmação está incorreta. A função mail não necessita de autenticação para enviar e-mails, apenas necessita que o servidor SMTP funcione correctamente.

Comment: A parte do meio também, pois o echo está completamente furado.

Answer (score -2):

Postei o script em um arquivo .rar no Google Drive para você efetuar download.

Eu utilizo sempre em meus sites este script que possui validação e verificação do servidor de saída (SMTP) para evitar que seu e-mail falhe ou caia na caixa de spam. Em grande maioria das vezes funciona sem problemas, basta configurar os dados no arquivo **enviar_email.php** não se esqueça disto!

Não se esqueça de enviar juntamente a pasta do **PHPMAILER** para o servidor.

> [BAIXE AQUI](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6z8ffELRxrJVFB3SkphV0VBZUE/edit?usp=sharing)
>
> *Para baixar, basta ir na guia Arquivo >> Fazer Download ou CTRL + S